# Merge data from two mysql server

Tags: mysql, myisam, migration

I have two old mysql servers and now I bought a new server and I want to migrate the files to this server, my question is if I copy all those files to the new server will the mysql recognize this files, or do I have to change some options. Both servers are MyISAM and the new server as well.

UPDATED:
Ex:

```
server one:    
    table1
    table2
    table3

server two:
    table4
    table5
    table6

new server:
    table1
    table2
    table3
    table4
    table5
    table6
```

Comment: Are there any databases with the same name on both machines? Or users with the same name?

Comment: Only just the root with the same password. there is one database named ex: 'test' but the table's names are different.

Comment: Updated My Answer !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all tables are MyISAM I have good news !!!

A mysqldump, while it will work and is bitwise safer and conservative, is totally not required.

[Each MyISAM table is comprised of three files: .frm, .MYD, .MYI.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/myisam/info)

You should be able to simply move the tables into a new database folder.

The information_schema database will automatically detect the presence of the three files and update itself (specifically update information_schema.schemata). Here is proof that can happen:

While MySQL is still running do the following

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
mkdir thisisatest
mysql
```

Once you run **SHOW DATABASES;** you should see thisisatest appear as a database. That's because information_schema automatically updated itself and registered /var/lib/mysql/thisisatest as a database. MyISAM tables will regsiter itself the same way (specifically update information_schema.tables). **WARNING : THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE WITH InnoDB !!!**

Answer (score 1):

Export the tables with `mysqldump`. Make sure to filter out the tables/databases that you do not need to import or overwrite. Import with something like `mysql < import.sql`.